# Dell PowerEdge R740 - Num Lock toggling itself rapidly

Tags: windows, rdp, dell-poweredge, dell

We have been experiencing an unusual issue on our Dell Server. 
Num Lock has been toggling itself on and off to a point where it blocks keyboard input. 
This happens with no keyboards attached, no wired keyboards, no USB keyboard receivers and no keyboards connected via bluetooth.

This server also has an unresolved issue with Kaspersky Endpoint that causes VMs to reboot repeatedly. The issue is intermittent however Num Lock toggles especially fast when there is an active window to a VM rebooting due to Kaspersky.

The Num Lock issue still occurs with the Hyper-V role uninstalled and no VMs with Kaspersky installed.

All Hardware diagnostics return no issues. This has occurred for long enough for the server to have gone through many firmware updates, none have made any difference. Toggling occurred in Server 2016 and Server 2019. Locally on the host and via RDP to the host. When running Windows Server 2016 there were no issues with Kaspersky however there was an issue with backups and shadow copies that caused the server to hang for several minutes every 4 hours.
That issue was resolved with Server 2019.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running hyper-v and do you have open virtual machine sessions on the console of the server?  The sessions from the virtual servers might be going through to the console of the server.

Comment: Issue shows up with no sessions, connected locally. I thought a session was the issue at one point but the toggling does appear when connected directly, just less often.

Comment: How about an idrac connection or another remote software?

Comment: It does have iDRAC setup and enabled. Toggling still occurs within a VM window but I haven't yet seen the issue on the host itself via iDRAC, at the moment the host is not toggling on RDP either though.

Comment: Have tested with iDRAC disabled completely previously and issues still show up.